# I can't break out of while True loop in Python 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

```
import random


while True:
    dice_number = random.randint(1, 6)

    print('You rolled ' + str(dice_number))

    print("Do you wish to continue? [Y/n]" )
    if input() == 'Y' or 'y':
        pass
    else:
        break
```

I just wasted half an hour trying to figure this out, still don't know what I did wrong. Can anyone help me please

Comment: The `or 'y'` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: Endlessly duplicated, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/15112125/3001761

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do `or == 'y'`. You have to put the whole logic expression again. Like this:

```
import random


while True:
    dice_number = random.randint(1, 6)

    print('You rolled ' + str(dice_number))

    print("Do you wish to continue? [Y/n]" )
    a = input()

    if a == 'Y' or a == 'y':
        pass
    else:
        break
```

Comment: I'd recommend to use `a in ('Y', 'y')` for multiple choices.